# fixed table size when resize block

Tags: html, css

The problem is thet I have resizable whindow where I have table. But I need that this table shoul be the same size all time. And when I shrink it it just overflow with scroll bars.

There are two tables on the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghQhh.png): left is what I need, right is what I have.

As you can see it do not overflow verticaly and horizontaly it is any way shrinkin to some critical position and only the overflow.

Thank you

```css
.customtable {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.customtable-title {
 color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #60748c 0, #48586b 33%, #303030 100%);
 text-align: left;
}

.customtable-title-cell {
 padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .5em .6em .4em .6em;
 white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customtable-title-cell:hover {
 opacity: .8;
 background-image: none, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.customtable-title-cell:nth-child(even) {
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
 border-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.customtable-grid-row:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #afafaf;
 color: #000000;
}

.customtable-grid-row:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #4e4e4e;
 color: #ededed;
}

.customtable-grid-row:hover {
 background-image: none, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.customtable-grid-row td {
 padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: .4em .6em;
 white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customtable-grid-row td:nth-child(even) {
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
 border-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class = "customtable" style="overflow:auto;">
 <div>
  <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
   <colgroup>
    <col style="width:100px">
    <col style="width:100px">
   </colgroup>
   <thead class="customtable-title">
    <tr>
     <th class="customtable-title-cell">Month</a></th>
     <th class="customtable-title-cell">Sales</a></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div>
  <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
   <colgroup>
    <col style="width:100px">
    <col style="width:100px">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$ 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$ 10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is is put the table in a div with a fixed height and width, and also have set the table height and width as fixed. For example like this:

```
.fixed-div{
    height: 180px;
    width: 160px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.fixed-table{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here is you whole code with some other small fixes (I also created some extra rows just to show how this works):

```css
.fixed-div{
    height: 180px;
    width: 160px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.fixed-table{
    width: 200px;
}

.customtable {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.customtable-title {
 color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #60748c 0, #48586b 33%, #303030 100%);
 text-align: left;
}

.customtable-title-cell {
 padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .5em .6em .4em .6em;
 white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customtable-title-cell:hover {
 opacity: .8;
 background-image: none, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.customtable-title-cell:nth-child(even) {
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
 border-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.customtable-grid-row:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #afafaf;
 color: #000000;
}

.customtable-grid-row:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #4e4e4e;
 color: #ededed;
}

.customtable-grid-row:hover {
 background-image: none, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.customtable-grid-row td {
 padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: .4em .6em;
 white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customtable-grid-row td:nth-child(even) {
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
 border-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="customtable" style="overflow:auto;">
 <div class="fixed-div">
  <table style="table-layout: fixed;" class="fixed-table">
   <colgroup>
    <col style="width:100px">
    <col style="width:100px">
   </colgroup>
   <thead class="customtable-title">
    <tr>
     <th class="customtable-title-cell">Month</th>
     <th class="customtable-title-cell">Sales</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$ 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$ 10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$ 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$ 10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$ 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customtable-grid-row">
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$ 10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/zyTn5Bbu0q)

Answer (score 1):

Your *customtable* div needs explicit values for height and width, otherwise it will stretch to fit it's contents